# Wagtail Admin Two Factor Authentication

Tags: wagtail

Is it possible to add 2fa Authentication to Wagtail Admin login page.

Comment: If you have multiple questions, please ask them in separate posts - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts .

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the Wagtail admin login page uses Django's built-in authentication framework, so it's possible to incorporate any of the various 2FA packages for Django, such as [django-otp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-otp). If you need to replace the login page with a custom view, you can do that by defining a URL route for `r'^admin/login/$'` in urls.py, making sure to place it above the route for `r'^admin/'`.

You could also look at [wagtail-yubikey](https://github.com/ahopkins/wagtail-yubikey), a Wagtail-specific solution using the YubiKey device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! With a little bit of hokiness. I mean, the login screen is now a plain bootstrap rather than the nice looking wagtail one. But, this will get you there with a ton of options such as using Google Authenticator. Here's what I did:

- Used [Django Two-Factor](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) and followed documentation.

Additionally:

- Added a link to `{% url 'two_factor:profile' %}` in the Wagtail account template `/templates/wagtailadmin/account/account.html`so the user can manage.
- Added a link to back to the admin in the Django two-factor profile template `/templates/two_factor/profile/profile.html` b/c it just dumps the person on the manage screen.
- In urls, added the following:

  ```
  from two_factor.admin import AdminSiteOTPRequired
  from two_factor.views import LoginView

  admin.site.__class__ = AdminSiteOTPRequired
  # btw, AdminSiteOTPRequired will only lock the django admin in to a 
  # mandatory requirement, but not Wagtail and needs further work


  urlpatterns += [
      url(r'', include('user_sessions.urls', 'user_sessions')),
      url(r'', include('two_factor.urls', 'two_factor')),
      url(r'^admin/login/$',
          view=LoginView.as_view(), name='login'
         ),
      url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),  
  ]
  ```
- in settings, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/'`
- new users are sent to `/account/login/?next=/account/two_factor/setup/`